# Python web scrape with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am able to scrape this sites tables with no issue; however, to get access to the tables I customize I need to login first then scrape because if i do not i get a default output. I feel like i am close, but I am relatively new to python. Looking forward to learning more about mechanize and BeautifulSoup.

It seems to be logging in correctly due to the fact that I get an "incorrect password" error if I purposely enter a wrong password below, but how do i connect the login to the url i want to scrape?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv
import mechanize
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("http://www.barchart.com/login.php")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['email'] = 'username'
br.form['password'] = 'password'
br.submit()

#print br.response().read()

r = urllib.urlopen("http://www.barchart.com/stocks/sp500.php?view=49530&_dtp1=0").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find("table", attrs={"class" : "datatable ajax"})

headers = [header.text for header in tables.find_all('th')]

rows = []

for row in tables.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])


with open('snp.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)

#from pymongo import MongoClient
#import datetime
#client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

print soup.table.get_text()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that you actually need to login to retrieve the URL in your question; I get the same results whether logged in or not.

However, if you do need to be logged in to access other data, the problem will be that you are logging in with `mechanize`, but then using `urllib.urlopen()` to access the page. There is no connection between the two, so any session data gathered by `mechanize` is not available to `urlopen` when it makes its request.

In this case you don't need to use `urlopen()` because you can open the URL and access the HTML with `mechanize`:

```
r = br.open("http://www.barchart.com/stocks/sp500.php?view=49530&_dtp1=0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(), "html.parser")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The url still can be accessed without being logged in; however, the problem is that when you access the url from a browser or python without doing so it sends you the default table setup. Once you log in it then shows the correct table i need. i tried what you suggested, but it is still sending me the default headers. I think there may be something wrong with my mechanize setup?

Comment: You know what I forgot that I used login with FB and it connected to my account that way when i set it up so the code did not actually recognize the password. I added a password and I am now getting the custom table i built while logged in. Thanks a ton Cheers!